# Split string to array from text and html tag

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string like

```
string html = "truongpm<b><i>bold italic</i></b><b>bold</b><i>italic</i>";
```

How do i get array like

```
a[0] = "truongpm", a[1]= "<b><i>bold</i></b>", a[2]="<b>bold</b>", a[3]="<i>italic</i>"
```

from this string. Now i use this code

```
string tagRegex = @"<\s*([^ >]+)[^>]*>.*?<\s*/\s*\1\s*>";
MatchCollection matchesImgSrc = Regex.Matches(html, tagRegex, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);
        foreach (Match m in matchesImgSrc)
```

But it just get

```
a[0]= "<b><i>bold</i></b>", a[1]="<b>bold</b>", a[2]="<i>italic</i>"
```

there are no "truongpm"
Please help me!
Thank

Comment: Put `[^<>]+|` before your current pattern.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code you can use:

```
var l = new List<string>();
var html = "truongpm<b><i>bold italic</i></b><b>bold</b><i>italic</i>";
var tagRegex = @"[^<>]+|<\s*([^ >]+)[^>]*>.*?<\s*/\s*\1\s*>";
var matchesImgSrc = Regex.Matches(html, tagRegex, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);
foreach (Match m in matchesImgSrc)
    l.Add(m.Value);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your RegExp only matches strings within tags. If you want to capture strings without any tag too, you must add an alternative to your regular expression. This can be done by adding `([^<>]+)` so that your expression would look like `([^<>]+)|{your existing expression}`.
On Websites like [Regex Pal](http://regexpal.com/) you find assistance in creating regular expressions.