# How to split text with HTML tags to array

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1, win-universal-app

I have very simple text with HTML (only `<b>` tag) e.g.

`Lorem Ipsum is <b>simply dummy</b> text of the printing and <b>typesetting industry</b>`

I would like to split the text to array like this:

```
[0] - Lorem Ipsum is 
[1] - <b>simply dummy</b>
[2] - text of the printing and
[3] - <b>typesetting industry</b>
```

The text inside HTML tag must be separated from another text. Is there any simple solution for it?

Thank you

Comment: have you tried something using `Split()` function or using regular expressions?

Comment: ^ for your knowledge. Html cannot be parsed correctly with regex http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: But in this case you can instantiate an array and add `[0] - Lorem Ipsum is` till you find <b>. When you find <b>, you search for the next </b> and you place the between text in the array `[1] - <b>simply dummy</b>` and so on. Like a minimal parsing algorithm. This will work if you don't have nested <b>'s.

Comment: there's a lib called htmlagility pack that does this for you if you're allowed to use 3rd party libs.

Comment: @kubakista It will: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29139320/split-string-to-array-from-text-and-html-tag

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may achieve this using following code

```
string value = @"Lorem Ipsum is <b>simply dummy</b> text of the printing and <b>typesetting industry</b>";
var parts = Regex.Split(value, @"(<b>[\s\S]+?<\/b>)").Where(l => l != string.Empty).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

I just wrote this, tested it and it works. It's a bit ugly but it works hahah

```
    public string[] getHtmlSplitted(String text)
    {
        var list = new List<string>();
        var pattern = "(<b>|</b>)";
        var isInTag = false;            
        var inTagValue = String.Empty;

        foreach (var subStr in Regex.Split(text, pattern))
        {
            if (subStr.Equals("<b>"))
            {
                isInTag = true;
                continue;
            }
            else if (subStr.Equals("</b>"))
            {
                isInTag = false;
                list.Add(String.Format("<b>{0}</b>", inTagValue));
                continue;
            }

            if (isInTag)
            {
                inTagValue = subStr;
                continue;
            }

            list.Add(subStr);

        }
        return list.ToArray();
    }
```