# jQuery get array of text at level 0

Tags: jquery

I have a string:

```
  "some text 0 <span>span 0 </span>some text 1<span>span 1</span>"
```

I would like to transform it into some kind of structure like:

```
[
    { text: 'some text 0' },
    { span: 'span 0' },
    { text: 'some text 1' },
    { span: 'span 1' }
]
```

I know I can cast it to jquery and use find to get an array of spans, but is there a way to get an array as above?

Thanks!

Comment: what you should try for this?

Comment: Are there ever any elements nested inside the `<span>`s?

Comment: no, the spans are all at that level, and there is nothing nested in them but text

Comment: Check this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30455489/how-to-split-text-with-html-tags-to-array

Comment: @MustafaTığ Using regular expressions to parse HTML often makes code more complicated than it has to be. In this case, Javascript already has built-in HTML parsers, better to use them than to resort to a regular expression

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because jQuery doesn't have very convenient methods for dealing with *text nodes*, I would prefer to use built-in Javascript to iterate over the `childNodes` and then `.map` them, extracting the `textContent` of the node, and the `tagName` (if the node is an element), or `text` (if the node is a text node):

```js
const str = "some text 0 <span>span 0 </span>some text 1<span>span 1</span>";
const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(str, 'text/html');
const arr = [...doc.body.childNodes]
  .map((node) => ({
    [node.nodeType === 3 ? 'text' : node.tagName.toLowerCase()]: node.textContent
  }));
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType) - a type of 3 indicates a text node

Answer (score 1):

Using regular exp, you can try as follows.

```js
const regex = /([a-zA-Z0-9 ]*)\<span\>([a-z0-9 ]*)\<\/span\>/gm;
const str = `some text 0 <span>span 0 </span>some text 1<span>span 1</span>some<span>span 1</span>`;
let m;
let ar = [];
while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        //console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
        if(groupIndex == 1){
          ar.push({"text":match});
        }
        else if(groupIndex == 2){
          ar.push({"span":match});
        }
    });
}
console.log(ar);
```